# Exctracting values from txt file in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have txt file with the following format:

```
(4, 'AF', 'AFG', 'Afghanistan'),
(248, 'AX', 'ALA', 'Aland Islands'),
               .
               .
               .
```

I want to extract the number and the country. My idea is to use `gsub` with `"[^0-9]"` to find the number and something like `tail(strsplit())` to extract the last word, after offcure I have removed all the special characters. Is there a a quicker way?

Data:

```
structure(list(V1 = c("(4, 'AF', 'AFG', 'Afghanistan'),", "(248, 'AX', 'ALA', 'Aland Islands'),", 
"(8, 'AL', 'ALB', 'Albania'),", "(12, 'DZ', 'DZA', 'Algeria'),", 
"(16, 'AS', 'ASM', 'American Samoa'),", "(20, 'AD', 'AND', 'Andorra'),"
)), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: try a `strsplit` on the `,` then take the first and the fourth column ?

Comment: @mpizosdimitris can you put a dput of (the head of) your data in the question? Makes solving things easier.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: I did not asked for a solution. I asked for an alternative method. I don't see a reason why you downvoted. Anyway, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data.frame is called `df`, here is a way using `regex`:

Get the first number:

```
sub("^\\((\\d+).*", "\\1", df$V1)
#[1] "4"   "248" "8"   "12"  "16"  "20"
```

Get the country:

```
sub("[^a-z]+([A-Z][a-z A-Z]+).+", "\\1", df$V1)
#[1] "Afghanistan"    "Aland Islands"  "Albania"        "Algeria"        "American Samoa" "Andorra"
```